# add value to textarea based on selected autocomplete option in opencart

Tags: php, jquery, json, textarea, opencart

One new column added to DB by me to add descriptions to attributes in Opencart and i can easily add/edit descriptions from admin panel but i have a problem in product_form page. I want to add automatically attribute description to every product when i choose attribute name.
In Opencart admin can choose attributes for products from autocomplete box but every time admin should add attribute descriptions manually. For example attribute 'Gold'. Every time when admin choose attribute 'Gold' he have to add description for gold manually. I want to retrieve attribute description from DB column 'protext' to automatically fill related textarea when admin. So when selected 'Gold' from input box related  text should be appear in related textarea for description.

This is code that edited by me in product form but doesn't work.
your help will be appreciated.

```
function attributeautocomplete(attribute_row) {
    $('input[name=\'product_attribute[' + attribute_row + '][name]\']').autocomplete({
        'source': function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php?route=catalog/attribute/autocomplete&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&filter_name=' +  encodeURIComponent(request),
                dataType: 'json',           
                success: function(json) {
                    response($.map(json, function(item) {
                        return {
                            category: item.attribute_group,
                            label: item.name,
                            label2: item.protext,                           
                            value: item.attribute_id                            
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        'select': function(item) {                      
            $('input[name=\'product_attribute[' + attribute_row + '][name]\']').val(item['label']);
            $('input[name=\'product_attribute[' + attribute_row + '][attribute_id]\']').val(item['value']);             
            $('input[name=\'related\']').val('');
        }
        $('textarea[name=\'product_attribute[' + attribute_row + '][product_attribute_description][text]\']').autocomplete({
            'append': function(item) {
            $('textarea[name=\'product_attribute[' + attribute_row + '][product_attribute_description][text]\']').val(item['protext']);
            }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: This is a urgent question. Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to change code in Controller file from where ajax is returning result. Path Admin > Controller > Catalog > Attribute -> function autocomplete(). Add "protext" code after name row or after any other key you want (I wrote 1 so that you can find code in file and can add after this)

```
'name'            => strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')),
```

line

```
'protext'          => html_entity_decode($result['protext'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
```

This is how, you will get this in tpl file.

- Database is already fetching with * so you don't need to change any code there.
- You already added code for tpl so it will work fine.

Note - It's better to make these changes using vqmod or ocmod. My OC version 2.0.2.0

Comment: This issue done by me from first day of attribute.php editing:'protext'          => html_entity_decode($result['protext'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), problem is with product_form.tpl, i add necessary codes but i autocomplete now works only for first 2 attributes.

Comment: add this line in your select function             $('textarea[name=\'product_attribute[' + attribute_row + '][product_attribute_description][text]\']').val(item['label2']); and remove textarea autocomplet line, it will never call